# Save state between two activity through intent

Tags: java, android

I have 2 form activities. First one for personal information (first name, last name) with next button:

```
Intent nextIntent = new Intent(personal_information.this, education.class);
nextIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(nextIntent);
```

Second activity for education and school name with previous buttons:

```
public void previous(View view) {
    Intent backIntent = new Intent(education.this,information.class);
    startActivity(finishIntent);
}
```

I need `onSaveInstanceState` way for save what I write whenIi press next and previous.

Comment: see this https://www.codexpedia.com/android/save-and-restore-activity-data-in-android/

Comment: how i destroy activity after intent because in debug mode savedInstanceState is null

Comment: Activity saved instance state is not meant for sharing data between activities.  It's meant for an activity to save and restore its own state if it needs to be destroyed and recreated.  To share data between activities, you should use intent extras.